# Xamarin.Android - Object is null after initialization

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

This is code of the Object:

```
[Serializable]
public class AppConfig
{
    public static string host {
        get{ return "192.168.1.133";}
    }

    public static int port {
        get{ return 2456;}
    }

    public bool autoLogin;
    public static StartupData startupData;
    public StartupData savedStartupData;

    public void SaveStartupData (StartupData sd)
    {
        this.savedStartupData = sd;
        AppConfig.startupData = sd;
    }
}
```

If I initialize the Object inside the Catch Exception block:

```
try {

} catch (Java.IO.FileNotFoundException ex) {
    //Do something here
    AppConfig appConfig = new AppConfig ();
    appConfig.SaveStartupData (startupData);
}
```

then the appConfig variable is null. But on the contrary If I initialize it outside the Catch Exception then appConfig is not null.
I don't know why, It is so absurd. Everybody please explain to me.

Comment: Are you sure it's really null, perhaps the debugger is playing up. Try adding Android.Util.Log.Info("TAG", appConfig == null ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL") and see what comes up in the android device log

Comment: there is no problem with the Debugger. I tried to get value of a unstatic variable but no success.

Comment: Just because you can inspect another variable doesn't mean the debugger is working correctly. There is every chance it's being optimized out for some reason.

Comment: If you are able to post some more complete code somewhere demonstrating the problem I would be happy to have a look

Comment: I have just edited the question, I wrote the code block where I meet the problem. In addition, when I am in debugging mode, I see the type of appConfig is object, not AppConfig type.

Comment: I created a project using your sample code and appConfig wasn't null. Here is the .cs file: http://pastebin.com/3P9h208k

Comment: Do you know why the type of appConfig variable was changed to object, not AppConfig type? I think it key to resolve my problem.

Comment: AppConfig is an object? I mean, all classes inherit from object... I'd still have to vote with the debugger possibility.